# UIButton Analog for reversesTitleShadowWhenHighlighted for Selected State

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, uibutton

I am using the `reversesTitleShadowWhenHighlighted` property on UIButton to reverse the title's text shadow(and it works great), but I really want the same thing for the selected state of the button(`UIControlStateSelected`).

Any answers to the related questions are also welcome:

- Is there a way to do this with a `UIButton` without modifications?
- Is there a way to set the shadowOffset of the title label per state with UIButton(similar to what is possible with the shadowColor)?
- If you were to extend UIButton to add this, how would you do it?

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem, so I guess it's no for your first two questions. Here is how I subclassed it :

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic) BOOL  reversesTitleShadowWhenSelected;

@end

@implementation MyButton

@synthesize reversesTitleShadowWhenSelected;

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    if (self.reversesTitleShadowWhenSelected)
    {
        if ((selected && !self.isSelected) ||
            (!selected && self.isSelected))
        {
            CGSize offset = self.titleLabel.shadowOffset;

            offset.width *= -1;
            offset.height *= -1;

            self.titleLabel.shadowOffset = offset;
        }
    }

    [super setSelected:selected];
}

@end
```